# Reversing the listview order

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, listview, adapter

I am updating my list view with received messages which are also stored in the database and placing the values at the top of the string using:

```
adapter.insert(message, 0);
```

Its working fine ,but am doing this thing in the fragment and fragment destroys when its closed, So when this fragment is alive again it get all the message from database, but when it update the list it completely reverse the list,Code updating the list from database is:

```
List<Message> values = datasource.getAllMessages(ch);
            ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
           setListAdapter(adapter);
```

So please help me know how to update the list in reverse order while getting values from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Collections.reverse` method

Answer (score 1):

> So please help me know how to update the list in reverse order while getting values from database

Use an appropriate [SQL `ORDER BY` clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) to define the order of the rows retrieved from the database and made available in your `Cursor`.

Comment: I just want to reverse the order of values in the cursor,thats all.

Comment: @Talib: And you do that by including an `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL that is used to create the `Cursor`.